# How to save multiple files to database rather than disk

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, kendo-ui, jquery-file-upload, kendo-upload

I tried to apply the method on [this](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/upload/index) page, but this sample save the files to disk instead of Database. So, could you please inform me what changes should be made on the sample method or is there any sample using this Kendo Upload to save multiple files to database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method declaration -

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetFileInfo(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
```

which receives the uploaded files have `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>` as parameter. It is collection of all the uploaded files. Each file exposes a property `InputStream`. For more information visit [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase(v=vs.110).aspx) msdn page

So now that you have the file content in form of stream, convert this stream into byte[] and save this to database.
Some suggestion are posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579373/saving-any-file-to-in-the-database-just-convert-it-to-a-byte-array).