# How to read blob from SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table with varbinary column:

```
My table {
   Id int primary key,
   FileBody varbinary(max)     
}
```

Now I want to read it. It's simple I can use code like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579373/saving-any-file-to-in-the-database-just-convert-it-to-a-byte-array) but it converts `varbinary` to `byte[]` and I want to avoid it.

Is it possible to put `varbinary` in `MemoryStream` without converting to a `byte[]`?

Comment: There is no conversion, think of it more like a buffer to move the data from the sql server into a memorystream. To save on memory you could use smaller buffers.

Comment: You can do this `new MemoryStream(myByteArray)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe You are searching for this:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
System.IO.Stream stream = reader.GetStream(1); // 1 is the index of the column
```

[GetStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetStream);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) method:

> Retrieves binary, image, varbinary, UDT, and variant data types as a Stream.

Comment: It's looks nice. Think that it what i looking for, Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can user a [`SqlDataReader.GetBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) to read data from the column or use [`SqlDataReader.GetSqlBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getsqlbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`SqlDataReader.GetStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstream(v=vs.110).aspx)

Example :

Using getBytes

```
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand( .... );
 ...
 SqlDataReader sqlReader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);
 byte[] outbyte = new byte[bufferSize]; 
 sqlReader.GetBytes(1, startIndex, outbyte, 0, bufferSize);
```

Using GetSqlBytes

```
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand( .... );
 ...
 SqlDataReader sqlReader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);
 byte[] outbyte = sqlReader.GetSqlBytes(1).Buffer;
```