# C# How to correctly save a binary image file from database?

Tags: c#

I am trying to export employee images from a database, save them onto my computer, then upload them to Salesforce in each employee's account. My problem is that there must be an issue with the way that I am saving the files from the database. When I go to upload to Salesforce the picture file pulled from the database, it tells me "your file cannot be uploaded at this time. please try again in a few minutes". However, when I email an individual picture to myself, download it, then upload that picture, it works. (I tried to do this en masse; it did not work). I have come to the conclusion that the issue might be with the code. The photo is stored as `varbinary(max)` and saved as both `.png` and `.jpeg` types, and extracted from the database using a variation of [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87z0hy49(v=vs.110).aspx)'s code:

```
   SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);

   connection.Open();
   SqlDataReader myReader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);

   while (myReader.Read())
   {
      filePath = @"C:\Users\npredey\Documents\Photos_from_database\" + myReader["first_name"] + '_' + myReader["last_name"];
      FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath + ".gif", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write); // creates a new file for output

      bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);

      startIndex = 0;
      retval = myReader.GetBytes(3, startIndex, outbyte, 0, bufferSize);

      while (retval == bufferSize)
      {
         bw.Write(outbyte);
         bw.Flush();

         startIndex += bufferSize;
         retval = myReader.GetBytes(3, startIndex, outbyte, 0, bufferSize);
      }

      bw.Write(outbyte, 0, (int)retval - 1);
      bw.Flush();

      bw.Close();
      fs.Close();
   }
   myReader.Close();
   connection.Close();
```

Could there be an issue with how the file is saved, where it would not be able to be uploaded? I have saved the file with all three acceptable extensions (`.gif`, `.jpg`, `.png`) and none of them have worked.

Comment: "The photo is stored as varbinary(max)" - but using what format?

Comment: @enkryptor edited.

Comment: Looks like you are storing your image data in a `Filestream` column, well done :) If you have the server option `Enable FILESTREAM for file I/O streaming access` enabled then you can access the data directly through Windows Explorer. That might save you a headache.

Comment: What do you mean "both .png and .jpeg"? Do you have two records per picture in your database?

Comment: @enkryptor no I mean that there are separate pictures (only one) that has either a `.jpeg` or `.png`

Comment: And you don't know, which is which? Could you show the query?

Comment: @enkryptor I do know which is which. The query is `"SELECT e.emp_id, e.first_name, e.last_name, ep.photo FROM HT_HOST.dbo.emp e JOIN HT_HOST.dbo.emp_photo ep ON e.emp_id = ep.emp_id";`, where `ep.photo` is the column containing the photo.

Comment: This one can be related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579373/saving-any-file-to-in-the-database-just-convert-it-to-a-byte-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On last write you shouldn't substract 1 from `retval`.

`retval` contains the numbers of bytes read.
The third parameters of `BinaryWriter.Write` is the numbers of bytes to write.

As you want to write all bytes you should only pass `retval` instead of `retval - 1`, which would keep the last byte from beign written.

Comment: This is what fixed it! Can you explain why this is the case?