# Saving Data to Database using fileuploadControl in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, file-upload

I have an multiple file upload control inside my form. I am trying to upload as many as files that users wants to database with a dropdown to choose the type of attachment. I am able to save the file to database but I get all 0's for my Data (0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000...00).
And when I'm trying to retrieve the file when user clicks on the file link, I get an error that syas "Failed to load the pdf document".

Here is my code for saving it to the database:

```
    public void getDynamicFilesFromUploadedFileList(int wWireTransferID, int wUserID)
    {
        if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow grow in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                try
                {
                    FileUpload fileuploadControl = new FileUpload();
                    fileuploadControl = (FileUpload)grow.FindControl("fUpControl");

                    DropDownList drpFileType = new DropDownList();
                    drpFileType = (DropDownList)grow.FindControl("ddlFileType");
                    Guid newID = Guid.NewGuid();

                    if (fileuploadControl.HasFile)
                    {
                       //I believe here is my mistake
                        Byte[] fileData = new Byte[fileuploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength];

                        new MRSManager().InsertWTDocument(wWireTransferID,
                             fileuploadControl.FileName,
                             drpFileType.SelectedValue.Trim(),
                             fileuploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType,
                             System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileuploadControl.FileName),
                             fileuploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength.ToString(),
                             fileData,
                             wUserID,
                             newID);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string m = "No File! ";
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception Exp)
                {
                    string msg = Exp.Message.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

And this is the code on How I try to retrieve the file.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the file id from the query string
        string id = Request.QueryString["ID"];

        // Get the file from the database
        DataTable file = GetAFile(id);
        DataRow row = file.Rows[0];

        string name = (string)row["FileName"];
        string contentType = (string)row["ContentType"];
        Byte[] data = (Byte[])row["Data"];

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        // Send the file to the browser
        Response.AddHeader("Content-type", contentType);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + name);
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.BinaryWrite(data);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();
        Response.End();
    }

    // Get a file from the database by ID
    public static DataTable GetAFile(string id)
    {
        DataTable file = new DataTable();
        string sSQL = string.Format("SELECT * FROM tblWireTransferDocuments WHERE FileID = '{0}'", id);
        file = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(DBConnection.GetConnectionString(), CommandType.Text, sSQL, null).Tables[0];
        return file;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579373/saving-any-file-to-in-the-database-just-convert-it-to-a-byte-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right

```
 //I believe here is my mistake
 Byte[] fileData = new Byte[fileuploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength];
```

You only created fileData, but didn't fill it. You should use fileuploadControl.FileContent to fill fileData.

Comment: You can create stream and read from it.
using(System.IO.Stream myStream = fileuploadControl.FileContent)
{
myStream.Read(fileData, 0, fileuploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength);

}