# save Dynamic Link Library (DLL) in database

Tags: c#, sql, dll

How can i save a DLL in sql table BINARY(n), and then retrieve it save on disk and reference to it, so the main application can use it? (c#)

Comment: Why you can save DLL to database? It's not good idea.

Comment: Ensure applications run correctly and trouble of Compile assembly at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

After you return the DLL from the database and save the file, you can then use the [AppDomian](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain(v=vs.110).aspx) class to load your DLL. Please refer to [AppDomainProject](https://github.com/nequeo/misc/blob/master/csharp/ConsoleLoadUnload.zip) for sample code.

Load the DLL call a method in the DLL and then unload the DLL

```
Nequeo.Reflection.AppDomianHost host = new Nequeo.Reflection.AppDomianHost(@"D:\Development\Version2015\Test\LoadUnload\ConsoleLoadUnload\bin\Debug");
int ret = host.Instance.ExecuteMethod<int>("ConsoleLoadUnload", "ConsoleLoadUnload.Test", "EntryPoint", new object[] { (int)6, (int)6 });
host.Unload();

textBox1.Text = ret.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2579467/1865718 for save file into database and get file from database.

Then you can use the dll through `System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(bytes);` or `System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom('File path');`.