# How to save collapsed layout of AspxPivotGrid to SQL Database?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, devexpress, pivot-grid

I am using **divexpress pivotgrid control**.

I want to do save and restore the layout. I can do that simply by using `Session`.
But I don't know how to save it into my SQL Database.

This code without database
**UPDATED**

```
protected void ASPxButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["Layout"] = ASPxPivotGrid1.SaveLayoutToString();

    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HQWebMatajer13"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [HQWebMatajer].[dbo].[ReportSave]([UserID],[ReportName],[UserFileName],[ReportData])VALUES('faisal.3012','TotalSales','faisalxxx',@ReportData)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportData", stream);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    //divServer.InnerHtml = Session["Layout"].ToString();
}

protected void ASPxButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text = "";
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HQWebMatajer13"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "select reportdata from [HQWebMatajer].[dbo].[ReportSave] where UserID='faisal.3012'";

        con.Open();

        string xxx = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(xxx);
        text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    ASPxPivotGrid1.LoadLayoutFromString(text);
}
```

**UPDATE:** Saving to database is working, but when i try to restore from database it throws the following error

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\System.Byte[].

on this line

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(xxx);
```

I don't know any idea about how to convert and where to convert. The same question asked in devexpress in [this link.](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T406714). They referred to [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579373/saving-any-file-to-in-the-database-just-convert-it-to-a-byte-array). But the convertion I don't understand how to make it into my scenario.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select reportdata from [HQWebMatajer].[dbo].[ReportSave] where UserID='faisal.3012'
```

You check what is the output of the above line in the DB.

You may have not initialized the variable byteArray with grid data. Break code at

```
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
```

and check what you are storing in to DB.