# Asp.net Edit Word document and save it to a DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

so the question says it all, I need to open a word document, edit it and save it to my database.

How can I do it, what can I use do to such thing ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving any file to in the database, just convert it to a byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579373/saving-any-file-to-in-the-database-just-convert-it-to-a-byte-array)

Comment: Web Forms? MVC? Core? What is triggering the opening of the word doc? How is it being edited? What database platform are you using? Your question is way too broad for StackOverflow. Try to narrow the scope of the question and/or break it down into smaller chunks, each getting it's own question. Also of importance is what have you tried to date?