# Docusign API to get byte[] for document in envelope

Tags: c#, rest, model-view-controller, docusignapi

I am developing MVC web application with c# utilizing Docusign API.
This is REST API that Docusign provides.

```
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}
```

When I call this HTTP request, Windows pops up and ask user to select the folder and set name of file to save the document in PDF format.

I would like to get `byte[]` value for the document so that I can save it to BLOB in db.

Is there any way to call this Docusign API to get `byte[]`?
I am new to programming and any help or advise will help.

Thank you.

Comment: If you have access to the file then you can do `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path)` to get the byte[].

Comment: I don't have access to the file unless I download the file from Docusign which I am trying to do by getting byte[] and save db.

Comment: You should accept answer to your other qs as well so that it benefits others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code should look like below:

```
// GetDocument() API call returns a MemoryStream

MemoryStream docStream = (MemoryStream)envelopesApi.GetDocument(accountId, envelopeId, documentId);
```

Above method uses [DocuSign's C# SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/test/SdkTests/LegacyAuthUnitTests.cs) , check `LegacyListDocumentsAndDownloadTest` method.

To Write MemoryStream to Database:

```
public static int databaseFilePut(MemoryStream fileToPut) {
        int varID = 0;
        byte[] file = fileToPut.ToArray();
        const string preparedCommand = @"
                    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Raporty]
                               ([RaportPlik])
                         VALUES
                               (@File)
                        SELECT [RaportID] FROM [dbo].[Raporty]
            WHERE [RaportID] = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
                    ";
        using (var varConnection = Locale.sqlConnectOneTime(Locale.sqlDataConnectionDetails))
        using (var sqlWrite = new SqlCommand(preparedCommand, varConnection)) {
            sqlWrite.Parameters.Add("@File", SqlDbType.VarBinary, file.Length).Value = file;

            using (var sqlWriteQuery = sqlWrite.ExecuteReader())
                while (sqlWriteQuery != null && sqlWriteQuery.Read()) {
                    varID = sqlWriteQuery["RaportID"] is int ? (int) sqlWriteQuery["RaportID"] : 0;
                }
        }
        return varID;
    }
```

or you can also check

[How to Store and Read Byte Array](https://www.morgantechspace.com/2014/05/How-to-Store-and-Read-Byte-Array-in-SQL-Server-using-CSharp.html) and [2579373](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579373/saving-any-file-to-in-the-database-just-convert-it-to-a-byte-array)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.