# save a text file into sql Database

Tags: ssis, etl, business-intelligence

I need to save a text file from my local disk to a sql database.
I'am using SSIS with Import Column

[image: ssis flow]

but I'am getting this error .

> [test [92]] Error: Opening the file "Anexceptionerror" for reading failed. The file was not found.[test [92]] Error: SSIS Error Code
> DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "test" failed because error
> code 0xC02090BB occurred, and the error row disposition on
> "test.Inputs[Import Column Input].Columns[attach]" specifies failure
> on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified
> component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more
> information about the failure [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code
> DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "test"
> (92) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Import
> Column Input" (93). The identified component returned an error from
> the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but
> the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.
> There may be error messages posted before this with more information
> about the failure.

Comment: tell your manager that this is a bad idea. What database BTW, SQL Server, MySQL,...?

Comment: It's an sql server database .Can you share arguments why?

Comment: Sure: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/306887/should-i-use-sql-vs-nosql-for-files-catalog/306909#306909 
Use RDBMS for raw data, NoSQL for files.

Comment: Thank you Francesco.. but I  they still  want to get with this solution.

Comment: The error message you are showing almost looks like a permissions issue or incorrect path where the SSIS package can not open the file.
Are you looking to save a file in the database that can later be retrieved as a file. Or are you needing to ingest the data from a file to be used to write queries against.  Here is a question about saving a file to the database https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579373/saving-any-file-to-in-the-database-just-convert-it-to-a-byte-array

Comment: You have to enable FILESTREAM. Follow this guide: https://codingsight.com/storing-files-in-sql-database-using-filestream-part1/

Comment: @peston It seems like that ,but i'am using just a flatfile source in which i do specify my file path.I need to the transfer the files on my local disk to the database